# Add additional product to cart via an observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, cart, event-observer

I have a checkbox in product view page and if it is checked and user clicks on "Add to Cart" I want to add additional product to the cart.

How to do this with an observer? Which event I need to watch?

EDIT: This seems to work

```
public function cartProductAddAfter()
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku('X6020R-652');
    $qty = 1;
    $productToAdd = $product->load($productId);
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cart->addProduct($productToAdd, $qty);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added to cart successfully.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked.

```
public function cartProductAddAfter()
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productId = $product->getIdBySku('X6020R-652');
    $qty = 1;
    $productToAdd = $product->load($productId);
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cart->addProduct($productToAdd, $qty);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added to cart successfully.');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for (unable to mark it as duplicate): [Original answer by MageWorx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671376/4575144)

Declare event observers in `config.xml`:

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <checkout_cart_product_update_after>
        <observers>
            <custommodule>
                <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                <method>cartProductUpdateAfter</method>
            </custommodule>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
</events>
```

Develop the Observers handlers:

```
class Vendor_Custommodule_Model_Observer 
{
    /* If you'd like to do the same while updating the shopping cart*/
    public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
    {
        $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
    }

    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $currentItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $currentItem->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();

        /* Detect Product ID and Qty programmatically */
        $idToAdd = "ANY PRODUCT ID";
        $qty = 1;

        $productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        /* @var $productToAdd Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $productToAdd->load($idToAdd);

        $this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, $qty);
    }

    protected function _addProductToCart($product, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        /* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */
        if ($product->getId()) {
            $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls help with my post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284914/57334 @Stijn